# Changing Git URL for all local repositories

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, logstash-configuration, bitbucket-server

Recently, we migrated the Stash Git server to use HTTPS rather than HTTP. Now we have to update the URL in each of the repositories to use the new URL with HTTPS. Is there any way we can attain this without going to each of the repositories' Git config and changing the URL? The problem is we have almost 60 local repositories which we have to update.

Any solution to update the URL in one shot is much appreciated .

Comment: Is there any reason you can't handle this at your reverse proxy? Simply put a 301 redirect that sends http --> https. Git can and will follow HTTP redirects, and this is one of the most common solutions to this problem that I have seen Stash/Bitbucket Server users implement. If you're not using a reverse proxy but are hitting the Tomcat webserver directly, you can still achieve an http --> https redirect - Atlassian has documentation for 3/4.x versions of Stash/Bitbucket, and newer instructions for the Spring Boot based 5.x version of Bitbucket Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `sed`, but be careful ;)

```
sed -i 's/git.oldserver.com/git.newserver.com/' /path/to/repos/*/.git/config
```

This will do an in-line string replace, replacing the old string with the new string. You just need to pass it the path to all the git config files.

Comment: We are in a windows environment. So does sed works in there? again the repos are spread in different folders.

Comment: I am honestly unsure how to do this using native Windows commands, sorry :(

Answer (score 6):

Each developer can globally configure the `url.<base>.insteadOf` setting:

```
git config --global url."https://your-domain".insteadOf http://your-domain
```

[This will cause](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) URLs beginning with `http://your-domain` to be dynamically rewritten to start with `https://your-domain`:

> Any URL that starts with this value will be rewritten to start, instead, with `<base>`. In cases where some site serves a large number of repositories, and serves them with multiple access methods, and some users need to use different access methods, this feature allows people to specify any of the equivalent URLs and have Git automatically rewrite the URL to the best alternative for the particular user, even for a never-before-seen repository on the site. When more than one insteadOf strings match a given URL, the longest match is used.